# Compressing images after upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, delayed-job

I have uploaded images using carrierwave and it is working fine. I have use delayed jobs in my project for my background task .I am looking for something so that i can compress my images when delayed jobs works I have no idea because i am new to ruby on rails .Can anyone tell me any gem or something but a detailed viw how to basically compress images using delayed jobs and carrierwave

Answer (score 2):

You Should use [carrierwave-imageoptimizer](https://github.com/jtescher/carrierwave-imageoptimizer)

Comment: but i won't compress the images the time i upload i want to compress the images using when my cron job works

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem Paperclip, it is quite easy to use and you can create your own processor to compress (or other operations) the images: 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor

Comment: you are not understanding what i try to meant